# git submodule no checkout

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repository with multiple submodules, like around 5 submodules.

I want to change the parent's and all the submodules `core.autocrlf` config to `input`.

My problem is that when I `git submodule update --init` or `git submodule init && git submodule update` the submodules are automatically checked out to HEAD, that is normal but I want to make it "not checkout" (no-checkout). I have not seen any options that would do that.

I am wondering if some people have this kind of situation and, did you have a workaround?

**Setting the config global is my last resort**

Comment: I'm confused - what do you want `git submodule update` to do if not make a checkout? And what does this have to do with autocrlf?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: i want to set `core.autocrlf` in each submodule before i check them out so the submodule files would use the correct line endings. If what I think im doing is correct :)